# wordpress url parsing using php - parse into php variable

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, url, canonicalization

hello wordpress/ url/ php experts I really appreciate your help in advance.

I set up a wordpress website and the url for example

www.domain.com/hello-world-how-are-you

so what i want to do is within single.php script, i want to parse the url and explode the url by "-" and take "hello" and "you" as a php variable.

i don't have too much knowledge on the server configuration, it would be great if this can be done using php only.

once again, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To grab the "page name"

```
<?php 
// gets you the path after http://www.yourdomain.com
$path = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$current_url = explode("-", $path);
$current_url = $current_url[1];

echo "path ".$path . "<br />" ;
echo "exploded url " .$current_url; 

?>
```

I was able to make this method work with preg_replace to grab arrays of each word (stripping out everything but numbers and letters in a string.

```
<?php 
// gets /beach/coast-guard-beach/
$path = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$preg = preg_split('/[^a-z0-9]/', $path);
foreach ($preg  as $key) {
    print $key. "<br /> ";
}
?>
```

prints:

beach
coast
guard
beach

Answer (score 2):

In short:

```
$url = 'hello-world-how-are-you'; // chop off the domain part first 
$parts = explode('-', $url); 
$var1 = $parts[0]; 
$var2 = end($parts);
```

The URL needs parsed first, check into the SERVER array (SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) and see what fits your needs. (via `error_log(print_r($_SERVER,1))`)